# how to give click and double click together in advanced datagrid flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I want to listen both click and double click events for advanced data grid in flex. I have given double click enabled true and written the function in itemdoubleclick but only click is working but not itemdoubleclick.Can any one please help me.
Thanks

Comment: You most certainly need to add code to your post, otherwise it will be nearly impossible to help you.

Comment: You have to double click on grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably did the right thing but the datagrid do not handle very well the click and double click, you can use a workaround to do that:

first the datagrid properties:

```
<s:DataGrid 
    dataProvider="{lista}"
    click="click(event)"        
    doubleClickEnabled="true"       
    doubleClick="doubleClick(event)">
```

then the click handler start a timer and if the timer successfully terminate the single click event is dispatched, otherwise if you double click the timer is stopped and you handle the double click event...

An example is better than anything else...

```
// A timer used to check if is a single or doubleclick
private var t:Timer;
protected function click(event:MouseEvent):void
{ // on single click you start a timer, the dalay 
  // is 500 but you can set what you prefer             
    t = new Timer(500,1);
    t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, singleClick);
    t.start();
}

protected function singleClick(e:TimerEvent):void
{
  // if the timer complete correctly this method is called and 
  // here you manage the single click event 
    t.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,singleClick);
    trace("single click");              
}

protected function doubleClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  // on double click you remove the timer event listener and you stop it if it's running
  // here you manage the double click event...       
    t.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,singleClick);
    if (t.running)
        t.stop();
      trace("double click");
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Does the doubleClick event interfere with the the single click? I've got a doubleClick in my mobile application which works as expected without that kind of workaround, though I don't have a single click event listener.

Comment: no in the datagrid is the single click that interfere with the double.. adding a eventlistener for single and double click without the workaround above, when you doubleclick, both single and doubleclick handler are fired... using the workaround above the single click handler wait for the dalay before being fired, if the doubleclick is fired the singleclick event does not continue...